# getiing data from database and show on Listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
while (cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    Message.massege(this,"Query "+cursor.getString(1)+"\n offer "+cursor.getString(0));
                    String[] fromFieldsname=new String[]{BankContract.Offers.Offers_COLUMN, BankContract.Offers.Query_COLUMN};
                    int[] toviewids=new int[]{R.id.offer_iid,R.id.Queriesofferlist_id};
                    SimpleCursorAdapter mycursoradapter;
                    mycursoradapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.offerlist, cursor, fromFieldsname, toviewids);
                    android.widget.ListView listview=(android.widget.ListView) findViewById(R.id.offerlist_id);
                    listview.setAdapter(mycursoradapter);
                    Message.massege(this, cursor.getString(0)+" Finally Done");
                    Log.d("all rows"," "+cursor.moveToNext());
                    if(cursor==null)
                    {
                        Message.massege(this,"offer column is null");
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate Model Class and recycler view adapter, then crate an array of that model class fill it with all data you get from cursor and pass it to adapter's constructor.